# How to set activiti task name dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, activiti

I need to set task name dynamically for activiti 7, just like below snippt code:

```
  <userTask id='theTask' name='${taskNameDynamically}' >
    ...
  </userTask>
```

I've search for this problem, but still cannot find any workaround yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use DelegateTask to set task name dynamically, with method: [setName](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/delegate/DelegateTask.html#setName-java.lang.String-)

example:

```java
    @Component("CustomTaskListener")
    public class CustomTaskListener implements TaskListener {
    
        @Override
        public void notify(DelegateTask task) {
                        
            task.setName("newTaskName");
        }
    }
```